# How to do fadeIn in jquery, and how to fit to all resulotions?

Tags: jquery, fadein

I've had a little practice in HTML, CSS, etc. I've done a little ticker.

In this ticker you can write in a text box, press on a button, and what you wrote will appear under. you can write as much as you want but in the screen we can see only the last three messages.

All the [code is in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mDmC/2/).

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#send").click(function(){
    var removed = false;
    var d = new Date();

    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();

    var outputDate = ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' +
        ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
         year ;

           var outStr = ((''+d.getHours()).length<2 ? '0' : '') + d.getHours() +':'+
        ((''+d.getMinutes()).length<2 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes();

    $(".element").animate({
        top:'+=3%'
    } , 400,  function(){
        if(removed == false)
    {
            removed=true;
            $('.third').remove();
            var temp1 = $('.first').html();
            var temp2 = $('.second').html();

            $('.first').remove();

            $('.elements .second').before('<div class="element first">'+
                '<img id="image" src="images/Picture.png">'+
                '<p class="date" >'+ outputDate +'</p>'+
                '<p class="time" >'+ outStr +'</p>'+
                '<p class="output" >'+ $('#input1').val()+
                '<p class="name" >'+ "Nina Pnina"+'</p>'+
                '</div>');

            $('.second').html(temp1);
            $('.elements .second').after('<div class="element third">'+temp2+'</div>');

        }
    $(".element").removeAttr("style");
        //$(".second").css("top","3%");
    });

  });
});

function clearContents(element) {
  element.value = '';
}
```

For now it's local on my pc so the photos will not appear in the jsfiddle, but it's quite understandable.

Now I want to do it more nice, so when a new message been sent, it will fade in and not just pop to the screen.

My second problem is that when I checked it on my laptop, all the ticker was a mess, I guess it's because the resolution. Does anyone know how can I fit the ticker to work on all resolutions?

Thanks!

Comment: http://bit.ly/XrQhhj Come this is so easy to google. No need to ask it here,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery `.fadeIn()`: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

you apply this to the created element, such as:

```
$(".element").fadeIn('slow');
```

it depends on what you want to fadein, etc. i edited your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/addiktedDesign/2mDmC/3/

and added `$(".first").fadeIn('slow');`

as well as hiding the added element (display:none;) on : `$('.elements .second').before('<div class="element first" style="display:none;">'`

on the resolution, i suppose you mean screen size, for which the background is an image, so is a bit complicated, would be better if you used css gradients, or flat color and use percentages for the widths, etc.

Comment: I have done it but it's not working. Can you show it to me in the jsfiddle?

Comment: see the update above, i did some edit to your fiddle. Note: I added a grey background behind the text just so you can see what it is doing, you can remove it, just otherwise the text is unseeable.

Comment: Thank you, Unfortunately it's not working on my pc.
Can I send it to you by mail and you can take a look?
Thanks again.

Comment: which bit is not working? the fadein? could you do a screenshot of what the original page looks like on your pc so that i can make sure the fiddle looks like that?

Comment: This is how it look on my pc
[IMG]http://i41.tinypic.com/2r3l377.jpg[/IMG]
It's a little bit small.

When I do the fadeIn It's just pop the first element, as before, and the fadeIn isn't working.

Comment: I have a picture in the back-ground, can this be the problem?
Is it possible that the fadein is in the back and I can't see it?
If so, do you know what I need to change in the css?

Comment: no, picture should be fine, maybe the code you have there is slightly different? The idea is that when you first add the element, it should be set to display:none; then using .fadeIn(); it will fade the element in. maybe you could upload all the images then link to these from the fiddle, and then i could check that?

Comment: I copy paste the code from the files into jsfiddle.
Can I send it to you via mail? It will be a lot easier I think. Thanks for all the effort!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31113/discussion-between-shlomi-and-addikteddesign)